# javascript array to string conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array in javascript:

```
[div.parts, div.editor, div.inside-1, div.container-2, div.inside-wrapper, div#content, div.whitebgpan, div, div#maindiv, body, html]
```

How can I convert it into string, so that the output will be:

```
div.parts div.editor div.inside-1 div.container-2 div.inside-wrapper div#content div.whitebgpan div div#maindiv body html
```

here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', function(e){
    var ClickedParents = jQuery(e.target).parents(); //Get all parents of clicked element
    var ClickedParents_array = jQuery.makeArray(ClickedParents); //Make array
    console.log(ClickedParents_array); //Show output in colsole
});
```

Comment: Can you please be clearer about your desired output format? It doesn't make sense to have a string built of DOM elements. Are you trying to log the text content of those elements, or...?

Comment: Hmm, didn't you ask this question yesterday as well? You've removed it, but this question looks awfully similar.

Comment: yes @Jack, I got negative rating on that question so I removed and now I post it again with more specific wording.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the jQuery `each` function and JavaScript's `Array.Join` function to solve this problem.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/zay015ex/1/

I've artificially retrieved an array of jQuery objects to show how you can solve this, but the concept is common to your problem.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="child3"></div>
    <div id="child4"></div>
    <div id="child5"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var arrayOfObjects = $('#parent').children();
var ids = [];

$.each(arrayOfObjects, function(i, val)
   {
       ids.push(val.id);
   });

var idString = ids.join(' ');
```

- You can read up more on the jQuery `each` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).
- You can read up more on the JavaScript's `Array.Join` function
  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: Sorry, I read the question wrong, it's jQuery objects. Let me fix the answer up.

Answer (score 0):

===== Update =====

Ok, the following code is tested, just open a console and paste this. it selects all div tags and convert into selector string.

```
$.map($('div'),function toSelector(elem){
    var jqObj = $(elem)
    var tag = jqObj.prop('tagName').toLowerCase()
    var classes = jqObj.attr('class') ? '.' + jqObj.attr('class').split(' ').join('.') : ''
    var ids = jqObj.attr('id') ? '#' + jqObj.attr('id').split(' ').join('#'): ''
    return tag + classes + ids
})
```

===================

Supposing they're jquery objects, you have to build the string manually.
For example, do something like following. (not tested)

```
function toSelector(jqObj){
  var tag = jqObj.prop('tagName').toLowerCase()
  var classes = jqObj.attr('class') ? '.' + jqObj.attr('class').split(' ').join('.') : ''
  var ids = jqObj.attr('id') ? '#' + jqObj.attr('id').split(' ').join('#'): ''
  return tag + classes + ids
}

array.map(toSelector)
```

Comment: This is giving me last value only, I tried $.each() but all in vain

Answer (score 0):

I think below code is helpful for you.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            String.prototype.replaceAll =    function  ( token, newToken, ignoreCase ) {
                var _token;
                var str = this + "";
                var i = -1;
                if ( typeof token === "string" ) {

                    if ( ignoreCase ) {
                        _token = token.toLowerCase();
                        while( (
                            i = str.toLowerCase().indexOf(
                                token, i >= 0 ? i + newToken.length : 0
                                ) ) !== -1
                        ) {
                            str = str.substring( 0, i ) +
                            newToken +
                            str.substring( i + token.length );
                        }
                    } else {
                        return this.split( token ).join( newToken );
                    }
                }
                return str;
            };
            try{
                var arr = [];
                arr.push('div.parts', 'div.editor', 'div.inside-1', 'div.container-2', 'div.inside-wrapper', 'div#content', 'div.whitebgpan', 'div', 'div#maindiv', 'body', 'html');
                var stringData = arr.toString();                
                stringData = stringData.replaceAll(",", " ");
                console.log(stringData);
       
            }catch(e){
                alert(e)
            }
        </script>
```